# How to access BatteryManager's BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the current from the API. There's a function at the bottom of the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) called getIntProperty, so I presume that'd be the function I'd need. However, up to now I've been simply using the getIntExtra function on an ActionBatteryChanged intent, and that same method doesn't work for this. What do I need to do different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is used to get the current value, not get updates like you do with a Broadcast and an Intent.  You'd call `batteryManager.getIntProperty(BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW)` to get the value.  Any of the BATTERY_PROPERTY_X constants could work, but not every phone supports all of them.

Comment: I presume I need to initialize a BatteryManager object in my code before calling this function, right? Would doing so affect any of the other code where I use BatteryManager without having initialized an object (such as with the EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, EXTRA_VOLTAGE, etc.)?

Comment: You would call (BatteryManager)context.getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE) to get the battery manager.  The object is set up for you by the framework, you don't new it.

Answer (score 2):

A more comprehensive code samples:
Declare this at the class level

```
private BatteryManager mBatteryManager = null;

onCreate()
{
    mBatteryManager = (BatteryManager) getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE);
}
```

Create a timer and inside the timer routine, add this

```
int mBatteryCurrent = mBatteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW);
```

The current is in uA unit. a positive integer means drawing current out of
battery and a negative integer means charging current into battery.